# How do I recover (binary) diagonal functor from more general case of diagonal functor to functor category?

Tags: category-theory

I'm teaching myself some category theory and trying to make sure I don't have too many holes in my understanding of basic concepts. I was hoping someone could explain (or point to a suitable reference) how the diagonal functor $\Delta: C \rightarrow C \times C$ is recovered from the more general case of $\Delta: C \rightarrow C^J$ by choosing an index category J consisting of a pair of objects (as for example mentioned in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diagonal_functor).

Comment: First, do you see that $C^2$ is isomorphic to $C \times C$?

Comment: Thanks - that starts to make some sense